# $regex to find a document in mongodb that contains a string

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am working on a db query in `mongo` where i need to query the document by regular expressing the `string` field(**fieldToQuery**).

the **datastructure** is like

```
{
     fieldToQuery : "4052577300",
     someOtherField : "some value",
     ...
     ...
}
```

I have the value like `"804052577300"`, using which i have to query the above document.

How to achieve the same using **$regex** operator?

Update:

I need to do like ends with `regex in mongo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a sort of reverse regex query where you create a regex using the `fieldToQuery` value and then test that against your query value:

```
var value = "804052577300";        
db.test.find({
    $where: "new RegExp(this.fieldToQuery + '$').test('" + value + "');" 
});
```

The [`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where) operator allows you to execute arbitrary JavaScript against each doc in your collection; where `this` is the current doc, and the truthy result of the expression determines whether the doc should be included in the result set.

So in this case, a new `RegExp` is built for each doc's `fieldToQuery` field with a `$` at the end to anchor the search to the end of the string. The `test` method of the regex is then called to test whether the `value` string matches the regex.

The `$where` string is evaluated server-side, so `value`'s value must be evaluated client-side by directly including its value into the `$where` string.

Note that `$where` queries can be quite slow as they can't use indexes.

Comment: thanks for your effort on this, will surely give it a try and will let  you know.
It'll be great if you could just give short explanation.

**update** : beauty, worked like a charm.

Comment: until the 'new RegExp' i understood, I figured out that we can use the field directly by seeing your 'this.fieldToQuery', but after that is little confusing.

Comment: @Beast No problem, I added some more explanation; hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
db.collection.find({ fieldToQuery: /4052577300$/})
```

The regex pattern above is equivalent to the SQL's LIKE operation:

```
select * from table where fieldToQuery like '%4052577300' => will return the document with the value "804052577300"
```

Comment: the value i said will be dynamic sequence prefixed with the number in the fieldToQuery. so i may have **"804052577300"** or **"8804052577300"**.